# Wordpress Image Gallery Per Post

Tags: wordpress, post, gallery

What is the best way to integrate an image gallery for each post in Wordpress?

I'm looking for a plugin that allows me to upload an unspecified number of images for each post which are then displayed in a gallery in a fixed position which is specified in the template.

My main reason for this is to provide a one-step solution without having to create an image album somewhere else first and then having to associate it in the post.

I tried NextGen Gallery and a few others, but couldn't find a way to achieve what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

WordPress comes with an in-built gallery maker that's available when you write posts or pages. More details http://codex.wordpress.org/Inserting_Images_into_Posts_and_Pages#WordPress_Gallery